# D3 quick chained transition inconsistency

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

When you chain transitions with a small duration, sometimes it skips the first one. It is not consistent. Sometimes 10ms doesn't work, but 5ms does. I used a setInterval with random duration in my demo so hopefully it will trigger for everyone http://jsfiddle.net/83rEC/. The code in question:

```
    .attr('fill', 'red')
    .style('opacity', 0)
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .style('opacity', 1)
    .transition()
    .attr('fill', 'green')
```

When that duration starts to get in the <10ms range is when it starts failing. Is it a bug in D3 or a logic failure on my part?

Comment: browser timing loops are typically 16.667 ms. Any time less than that is likely to be subsumed by the next event.

Comment: Aha that explains it. Thank you. If you answer I will mark solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

browser timing loops are typically 16.667 ms. Any time less than that is likely to be subsumed by the next event.